# jenkins: Start two jobs consecutively from gerrit event

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I would like to execute two jobs separetly with prioriry order on the same gerrit event.

My constraints are:

- Job 1 start and finish.
- Job 2 must start after the job 1 with the same gerrit event.

I enabled in job 2:

- Build after other projects are built
- Gerrit event

But the GERRIT_REFNAME is empty in job 2.

How can I proceed ?

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

**Job 1**

Use "Trigger parameterized build on other projects" to start Job2 at the end. Do not forget to add the "Current build parameters" option.

[image]

**Job 2**

Remove the "Gerrit event" trigger option.